# Pythonic way of saying "if all of the elements in list 1 also exist in list 2"

Tags: python

I want to return true from the if statement only if all of the elements from list 1 also exist in list 2 (list 2 is a superset of list 1).  What is the most pythonic way of writing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [set operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
if set(list1) <= set(list2):
    #...
```

Note that the comparison itself is fast, but converting the lists to sets might not (depends on the size of the lists).

Converting to a set also removes any duplicate. So if you have duplicate elements and want to ensure that they are also duplicates in the other list, using sets will not work.

Comment: What if the lists are `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: `set`s in Python are *AWESOME*.

Comment: @Gabi That means that the elements 1 and 2 are contained inside of set {1,2,3}. It should (and does) return true.

Comment: Does this not require duplication of storage of each list?

Comment: @Michael: Depends on elements in the lists. If you have objects, then only references are stored, the size does not duplicate. Of course you need some space for the sets. It is the typical tradeoff: Space vs Speed.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I know that, but from what the OP said, it should return `False`.

Comment: @Gabi Huh? If all elements of list A are found withing list B you can properly state that B is a superset of A. That is what the OP asked.

Comment: I did clarify by using the term "list 2 is a superset of list 1".  I think this solution looks good, and not at all awkward.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-in all() function:

```
if all(x in sLVals for x in fLVals):
    # do something
```

In case of using sets think you can take a look at [difference method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.difference#set.difference) as far as i know it is quite faster way:

```
if set(fLVals).difference(sLVals):
    # there is a difference
else:
    # no difference
```

Comment: Note that the run time of this is `O(N^2)`. In particular `x in sLVals` will be slow (linear search).

Comment: +1 for a solution which doesn't require a lot of extra storage.

Comment: Thanks, but i think that all method can be also used, not sure but for example set can't be used for a list of dicts and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Either `set.issuperset` or `all(x in L2 for x in L1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This one came straight out of [good folks at MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/download-course-materials/):

```
from operator import and_
reduce(and_, [x in b for x in a])
```

I tried to find the `"readings.pdf"` they had posted for the 6.01 class about a year ago...but I can't find it anymore.

Head to my profile and send me an email, and I'll send you the .pdf where I got this example. It's a very good book, but it doesn't seem to be a part of the class anymore.